# PIP by your subordinate

Tags: performance-reviews

I am the GM of a Plant and have been there for 9 years. Last year my HR Manager became upset at me over her salary negotiation. She happens to be my Payroll Manager also and complained because of what I made compared to her. She started to have people resist every direction I gave and refused to participate in areas I was working on to improve our training because she did not agree. She then went to all the employees and asked them to write any complaints they had against me and to keep a log so she could turn them into our corporate office. After a few month's she had a solid band of supporters and sent all the letters 
to Corporate.
I still do not know anything that was written, but our Corporate President and HR wanted to put me on a PIP and let our local HR and another of my reports administer it with weekly meetings. I could not manage them anymore since if I said anything negative it would be considered retaliation. They continually sent inaccurate PIP meeting notes to our Corporate HR. She told me as long as I just left everyone alone we could "move on". Other areas were needing help and when I did step in and insist on actions, she let our Corporate know I was intolerable to work with and her band of supporters backed her up. I am now losing my job because I couldn't "manage the situation".
I guess my question is, has anyone ever heard of them letting direct reports administer their bosses PIP?

Comment: Why does it matter if anyone has ever heard of this? You're not going to get your job back either way. Sorry if that seems harsh, but you're asking the wrong question here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! That’s the only way a remote corporate HQ will know about management that is ineffective.

However if another employee is rallying the troops then I’m sure there is a policy against that. Check your HR hand book and consult an attorney to see if you can keep your job and if there is any legal ground to fire you.

Even if you win, you should probably seek a new position elsewhere.

Comment: Unless some kind of coercion is involved in the rallying, it's probably not a bad thing. Everyone seems to have decided on who the leader is there.